# can't copy a file from local machine to a pod

Tags: kubernetes

i'm trying to copy a file from local machine to a HADOOP POD with kubectl :

```
kubectl cp /data/titles.csv -c namenode hdfs-namnode-0:/newfile/titles.csv
```

i get always this error :

```
tar: /newfile: Cannot open : No such file or directory
```

And newfile is already existing :

[image]

Comment: can you do `which tar` inside your container and let us know the output ?

Comment: @P.... i get  /bin/tar

Comment: The error is saying that `/newfile` path doesn't exist in the container. Maybe you should try `hdfs-namnode-0:/tmp/titles.csv`